# adding close button in popup box

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my simeple example of popup. I want to add close button on right top of popup window using css or jquery.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/EYAY2/

```
<a href="#popup" rel="popup">open</a>

<div id="popup" class="popup"> <a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>

</div>
<div id="new" class="popup">
    <textarea id="new-text"></textarea>
</div>
<a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>

<div id="new2" class="popup">NEW
    <textarea id="new-text2">text area 2</textarea>
</div>
```

any help?

Comment: :Where should the close button be added.Could you be more clear

Comment: r u want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/EYAY2/1/

Comment: @Shadow: it should be in popup, right top corner

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: it should be in popup windows

Comment: In my fiddle it is in top right on popup window only

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: thanks Suresh. I check it again. popup is white box. and also close button not close the popup

Comment: Ohhh ok. i will check that.

Comment: i have added my answer. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your HTML part like below.

```
 <a href="#popup" rel="popup">open</a>

 <div id="popup" class="popup"> <a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>
 <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;"><button class="clsbtn">close</button>     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="new" class="popup">
 <div style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;"><button class="clsbtn">close</button>    </div>
 <textarea id="new-text"></textarea>
 </div>
 <a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>

 <div id="new2" class="popup">NEW
<textarea id="new-text2">text area 2</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #lean_overlay {
position: fixed;
z-index:100;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background: #333;
display: none;
}
.popup {
background:#fff;
width:300px;
display:none;
min-height:150px;
}
```

Finally You need to add jquery for the close button functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clsbtn").on("click",function(){
  $(".popup, #lean_overlay").css("display","none");
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EYAY2/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add button tag in your HTML code as shown in follow

```
<div id="popup" class="popup"> 
<input type="button" id="button" value="close" />
<a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>
</div>
```

Add following code in CSS

```
#button {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

It'll work now.